# How to prepare dynamic request in rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am new to rest assured. Currently, I am working on API automation using rest assured. I have the following scenario to handle

We have two APIs (eg: API1, API2) , API1 will give the list of userdetails . I need to send these details as part of the second API request.

**API1 - Response**

```
    [ {
  "userSourceMeta" : {
    "userId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "source" : "BOX",
    "organisationId" : 1,
    "emailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "sourceUserId" : "16231222289",
    "sourceTeamId" : null
  },
  "connectionStatus" : null
}, {
  "userSourceMeta" : {
    "userId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "source" : "DROPBOX",
    "organisationId" : 1,
    "emailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "sourceUserId" : "88888222768",
    "sourceTeamId" : null
  },
  "connectionStatus" : null
}, {
  "userSourceMeta" : {
    "userId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "source" : "GDRIVE",
    "organisationId" : 1,
    "emailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "sourceUserId" : "8888873554753473",
    "sourceTeamId" : null
  },
  "connectionStatus" : null
}]
```

**API2 - Request :**. : In API2 request I need to send "sourceUserId", "source" details.

```
    {
  "query": "hi",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
  "sourceFilterInfo": [
    {
      "sourceUserId": "16055292089",
      "source": "BOX"
    },
    {
      "sourceUserId": "88888222768",
      "source": "DROPBOX"
    },
    {
      "sourceUserId": "8888873554753473",
      "source": "GDRIVE"
    }
  ],
  "contextIds": []
}
```

userSourceMeta details are dynamically change based on the user.
Please suggest to me how to prepare the API2 request based on the previous API responses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you're fimilar with POJO approach or not, but personally, it'd be the easiest way.

Note:

- you can extract static class to stand-alond class, no required it must be here.
- I use [Lombok](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok) and [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) as external lib.

```
public class DynamicResponse {

    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class SourceMeta{
        private UserSource userSourceMeta;
    }

    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class UserSource {
        private String userId;
        private String source;
    }

    @Data
    static class Request2 {
        private String query;
        private String timeZone;
        private List<UserSource> sourceFilterInfo;
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        //Save response of request 1
        List<SourceMeta> res1 = given().get("http://localhost:8000/req1")
                .as(new TypeRef<>() {});

        // Convert response 1 to list of UserSource
        List<UserSource> userSource = res1.stream()
                .map(SourceMeta::getUserSourceMeta)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Add list of UserSource to Request 2
        Request2 req2 = new Request2();
        req2.setQuery("hi");
        req2.setTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
        req2.setSourceFilterInfo(userSource);

        // Send the Request 2
        given().log().body().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(req2)
                .post("http://localhost:8000/echo");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have very little idea about POGO. I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way that we can do without POGO

Comment: @daithashankar Of course yes, could you tell me how you are making a request body, I will provide solution in the same way.

Comment: I created a JSON file with the request.  
I am reading this file and store it in a string. Calling the POST API request using the string as a BODY.  @lucasnguyen17

Comment: Oh man, manipulating string is the worst way to handle json, it's so rigid and unmaintainable.

Comment: Actually, My request is more than 1000 rows, I need to manipulate a few pieces of data for each scenario. So I followed this approach. Test data I am sending as part of the test (using cucumber data table).

Comment: You can get test data from cucumber table, then save it to Java Object, then put it in `body()`, rest-assured will automatically convert Java object to json if it sees jackson or gson lib in classpath of project. Now, I think I will stop follow this question because I don't want to manipulate string and I've already provide workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have two vId(1 & 2). I want to send it dynamically, if response is null for vId 1 then set vId as 2.

```
Response response = given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                   .param("name", Name).param("vIds", vId)
                   .when().get(EndPoint).then()
                   .extract().response();
```